# Facebook comments order change

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook seem to have changed the sort order of Comments on Root posts, requested via a graph api page/feed request.

Previously if we didn't specify a sort order we would have received the posts in a reverse chronological order (most recent first), however now it appears this order is driven from the page settings (Most relevant or chronological).

Does anyone know when this change occurred? It is affecting a version of our app that is in production.

Comment: This is a bug we're tracking here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/761924987245470/